# Arrange data by variables of a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, tidyverse, lubridate

I have written down the following script to get the data in `longer format`. How i can get the `data.frame` `arrange` by `variables` and not by `Date`?. That means first i should get the data for `Variable A` for all the `dates` followed by `Variable X`.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("1979-01-01"), to = as.Date("1979-12-31"), by = "day"),
                 A = runif(365,1,10), X = runif(365,5,15)) %>% 
      pivot_longer(-Date, names_to = "Variables", values_to = "Values")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I not understood wrigth, but you can arrange your data according to the variables column, through the `arrange()` function.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF <- DF %>% 
  arrange(Variables)
```

**Resulting this**

```
# A tibble: 730 x 3
   Date       Variables Values
   <date>     <chr>      <dbl>
 1 1979-01-01 A           3.59
 2 1979-01-02 A           8.09
 3 1979-01-03 A           4.68
 4 1979-01-04 A           8.95
 5 1979-01-05 A           9.46
 6 1979-01-06 A           1.41
 7 1979-01-07 A           5.75
 8 1979-01-08 A           9.03
 9 1979-01-09 A           5.96
10 1979-01-10 A           5.11
# ... with 720 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can use

```
DF1 <- DF[order(DF$Variables),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something?  This is it.

```
arrange (DF,Variables,Date) %>% select(Variables,everything())
```